# How Subscribe works

Tags: rxjs, observable, publish-subscribe, angular11

I am learning the rxjs and playing with observable and subscribe. I have the following method in **component.ts** file which returns true/false from API

```
this.http.get(apiUrl+"/actionName")
  .subscribe(result=> 
 {
 if(result){
     //step1
 //1.show success message 
  //2.call the other method 
  //3.and after returned from here
}else{// not true
 //1. show error message 
//2. returned from here
 }
});
});
 //step2
 // call another function
 }
```

Whenever I subscribe to an observable it immediately jumps to the next line i.e. step 2 and another method gets called first. Which I don't want to do.

I want to run step1 first until it gets finished completely only then it should go to step2.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Put the call to the second method within the callback.

Comment: I tried this but once the get() request is called it does not come inside .subscribe() instead of this it first comes out and executes step2.

Comment: look into concatMap

Comment: @Indraraj26 will this allow executing inner part of subscribe and than go to outside of this.

Comment: no when source change then inner will execute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say so in your question, but I suspect your

```ts
//2.call the other method
```

line contains a nested subscription or a promise. If that's the case, of course your synchronous code will be run before your asynchronous code is run. JavaScript is a single-threaded environment, so you can never wait for other code to run.

---

Instead, use RxJS various operators to manage the order of your code for you. How you want to do that depends on what you're doing, though sadly `call the other method` isn't descriptive enough.

Assuming theOtherMethod and anotherFunction are actually strangely named observables, then you might do something like this:

```ts
this.http.get(apiUrl+"/actionName").pipe(

  switchMap(result => {
    if(result){
      return theOtherMethod;
    }
    return of("There's no result")
  }),

  switchMap(otherMethodResult => anotherFunction)

).subscribe(anotherFunctionResult => {
  /* Ignore result?*/
});
```